# VB.NET arraylist display in a single row

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, textbox

I try to make an arraylist which can display all items in one row.

```
Dim listarray As New ArrayList
Dim JARLIB As String = "*.jar"
Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\libraries\")
Dim diarr1() As IO.FileInfo = dir.GetFiles(JARLIB, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim drar As IO.FileInfo
'list the names of all files in the specified directory
For Each drar In diarr1
    listarray.Add((drar.DirectoryName) & ";")
Next
elemante = listarray.ToString
RichTextBox1.Text = elemante
```

And that is not working, i must recive in TextBox something like

```
C:\User\file.jar;C:\User\file\file2.jar;
```

Can you help me ? Thanks !

Comment: I guess that you meant drar.Name or drar.FullName rather than drar.DirectoryName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listarray.ToString` won't return you all the elements of the `ArrayList`.

It seems you want something like this:

```
Dim listarray As New ArrayList
Dim JARLIB As String = "*.jar"
Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\libraries\")
Dim diarr1() As IO.FileInfo = dir.GetFiles(JARLIB, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim drar As IO.FileInfo
'list the names of all files in the specified directory
For Each drar In diarr1
    listarray.Add((drar.DirectoryName) & ";")
Next
For Each item In listarray
    elemante = elemante & item.ToString
Next
RichTextBox1.Text = elemante
```

Comment: is ok but now C:\Users\lwjgl_util\2.9.0 and file.jar is not appear

Comment: See a comment to your question